# EPSG900913 not working with WMTS layer

Tags: wms, openlayers-2, wmts

I am a GIS newbie and I am trying to get WMTS layers to work with OpenLayers 2.

I do the standard procedure:

1. Issue a GetCapabilities request.
2. Parse the response using OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities().read( )
3. Turn the response object into a layer using OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities().createLayer( ) using the matrix tile set and layer.

This all boilerplate OpenLayers code -- I didn't do much myself.  Everything works as expected for EPSG:4326, and some ArcGIS services I tried.  In fact, for the same service and layer - the EPSG:4326 tile set shows up but the EPSG:900913 tile set does not.

In fact, looking at the network response (in developer tools) when fetching the EPSG:900913 tile matrix set, I know I am getting the image tiles but they are not showing up onthe map.  The map is black for some reason.

I thought it was maybe because the projection is in EPSG:4326 when my tiles are in EPSG:900913.  After setting the base layer as the WMTS layer, I do:

```
  var projection = map.getProjection(); // Shows up correctly as EPSG:900913
```

It might useful to note that I had to override the below functions with the latest code code from the OpenLayers 2 github repo:

```
        OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities.prototype.createLayer
        OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities.v1_0_0.prototype.readers
        OpenLayers.Layer.WMTS.prototype.setMap
        OpenLayers.Layer.WMTS.prototype.getURL
```

Maybe I missed a function I had to override?  That's my best theory so far!